# Delete "orphaned" SSIS catalog

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

Not sure I am referring to this correctly, but we seem to have an "orphaned" or rogue Integrated Service Catalog, SSISDB, with a database SSISDB on an azure managed instance

We were testing SSIS options a few months ago including creating it in data factory. I know that's when it was created but the Azure-SSIS integration runtime is not in the data factory that is listed in

```sql
SELECT [property_name]
       ,[property_value]   
FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[catalog_properties]
```

The data factory is there but there is no Integration Runtime or any reference to SSISDB in there.

How do we delete the catalog?
Do we have to delete the entire data factory to remove this?

Edit: I have already dropped the SSISDB database to see if it helps, it didn't so restored it. the database itself is not the problem.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this particular scenario but, in general, the IR runtime in ADF provides only the libraries,dependencies and tools to run SSIS packages. These packages could reside in different catalogs; managed instances, azure sql, filesystems,etc. When you remove the IR from the ADF you are not removing any catalogs or package folders, these should be dealt with separately.

Comment: I'm not sure how to remove this I have tired different things and was wondering if maybe the adf needed to be deleted. atm getting login fail audit errors to SSISDB when developers login to server. tbh I know very little about ssis.
How do we deal with this separately, that's the problem?

Comment: This https://andyleonard.blog/2016/09/managing-the-ssis-catalog/ implies that dropping the DB removes the catalog. "If you want to delete the SSIS Catalog, drop the SSISDB database". Sounds like this isn't happening in your case?

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea. I renamed the database, had several errors trying to reconnect, for some reason the server tries connecting to SSISDB. But I finally got in & the catalog was gone. So though probably dropping DB might work in normal circumstances, for some reason on our Azure managed Instance dropping the db did not remove the catalog. Maybe it would have after a while, I don't know, but when I initially dropped it, the catalog didn't go anywhere for hours. and kept getting login errors for explicitly specified database 'SSISDB', I thought it broke something so I restored it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this so if someone else has the same issue
I renamed the database, had several errors trying to reconnect, for some reason the server tries connecting to SSISDB. But I finally got in & the catalog was gone. So though probably dropping DB might work in normal circumstances, for some reason on our Azure managed Instance dropping the db did not remove the catalog. Maybe it would have after a while, I don't know, but when I initially dropped it, the catalog didn't go anywhere for hours. and kept getting login errors for explicitly specified database 'SSISDB', I thought it broke something so I restored it.
So if dropping the database doesn't fix it, restore it, rename it wait a few minutes  for SSIS catalog to drop, then drop the database.